# What does the node command do with the -e argument passed

Tags: node.js

When I put node -e "some argument string" into the command line, what does it do? I cant seem to find any documentation on this from google and stackoverflow searches.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It evaluates the script argument

```
node -e "console.log('test')"
> test
```

You can can get help and info by running...

```
node -h
```

Or:

```
node --help
```